# Python Class with input data

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to create a function to get the worker with the biggest salary.
How can I write it?

```
dataclasses import dataclass
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import Self


@dataclass
class Worker:
    name: str
    surname: str
    age: int
    salary: Decimal

    @classmethod
    def data_input(cls):
        return cls(
            name=input('Name:\n'),
            surname=input('Surname:\n'),
            age=int(input('Age:\n')),
            salary=Decimal(input('Decimal:\n'))

        )

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.name}, {self.surname}, {self.age}, {self.salary}'
    
    
    @dataclass
    class WorkerService(Worker):
        workers = list[Worker]
    
        def get_worker_with_biggest_salary(self, workers: workers) -> Self:
            return
```

Comment: From where? Presumably, your function would take something like a list of `Worker` objects and iterate over them. Really, all you need is the built-in `max` function with an appropriate `key` argument, something like `max([worker1, worker2, ...], key=lambda w: w.salary)`.

Comment: Is your indentation like this in your actual code? Also, what is the purpose of `WorkerService`? Simply to track instances of `Worker`?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to create another class to take worker with biggest salary and I thought i need to use inheritance to do this

Comment: `WorkerService`, whatever it represents, is not a kind of `Worker`. You likely do not need another class just to wrap a list of workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to directly answer your question I would use the `max` built-in to get the largest salary.

```
class WorkerService:
    workers: list[Worker]

    def get_worker_with_biggest_salary(self):
        return max(self.workers, key=lambda worker: worker.salary)

    def __init__(self):
        self.workers = list()
```

However I would add that `WorkerService` should not be a `dataclass`. Dataclasses are suppose to hold information and that is about it. If you `class` has a bunch of functions that manipulate its state then it should just be a `class` and not a `dataclass`

Also for `Worker` you have a function called `data_input`. `dataclass` already lets you create the class that way. You should instead move input handling out of the class and then create the instance with what is inputted. Also `WorkerService` has an instance field called `workers` yet when you wrote `get_worker_with_biggest_salary` you take in an argument of workers. You should either take in the argument or use `add_worker` or `remove_worker` and then work off the instance field. Heres an example...

```
name = input('Name:\n'),
surname = input('Surname:\n'),
age = int(input('Age:\n')),
salary = Decimal(input('Decimal:\n'))

worker = Worker(
    name=name,
    surname=surname,
    age=age,
    salary=salary
)

worker_service.add_worker(worker)

highest_salary_worker = worker_service.get_worker_with_biggest_salary()
```